# Bash: compgen How to get rid of Warning message [option may not work as you expect]?

Tags: bash, compgen

I am making a simple bash completion program using compgen

however when using compgen -F  option, 
the warning message keep prompt out and break my list of work

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.  How can I get rid of this or debug it? Thanks

```
kithokit@09:54:25 ~ $ compgen -F a
bash: compgen: warning: -F option may not work as you expect
```

Comment: `help compgen` and `man bash` would be the correct place. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the warning like this:

```
compgen -F a 2>/dev/null
```

but unfortunately that will also discard any real error message from compgen.

As far as I can see from the bash source code, there is no other way to suppress the message, but I didn't look really deep.

Answer (score 1):

From `man bash`

> compgen [option] [word]
>   Generate possible completion matches for word according to the options, which may be any option accepted by the complete builtin with the exception of -p and -r, and write the matches to the standard output. *When using the -F or -C options, the various shell variables set by the programmable completion facilities, while available, will not have useful values*.

As this shows, you probably have some variable set to alter the behaviour of the bash  completion facilities and the option `-F` to `compgen` ignores those variables and values, informing you of this with the above warning.

References:
[1] http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash